# Making the app give an alert without running in the background or using notifications?

Tags: iphone, time, background, notifications, settings

I'm wondering if it's possible to make an iphone app give the user an alert in a certain time without being run in the background or using notifications?

I see it happening in an app called iPray Pro. It gives an alert for the prayer time even though it's not running in the background or using notifications. I checked under the Setting-Notifications and the app is not there at all.

How is it done?

Comment: is it doing some kind of calendar alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for Local Notifications in the iOS documentation. They are like push notifications, but don't require a server. They are quite simple API to use too; make a UILocalNotification and use the `scheduleLocalNotification:` method on `UIApplication` to add the notification onto the system.

It will then fire in accordance to the `fireDate` property of the local notification you scheduled.

Local Notifications require iOS4.0 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled local notifications will trigger even if the app is closed. iPray probably schedules notifications for a given time which are then triggered by the OS without the app having to be open.

Answer (score 0):

It is using Local Notifications, not Remote Notifications.